# Update a parent widget from a child widget using flutter-provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

How do I update the state of a parent widget `onTap` of a child widget using `provider`

Currently what I am doing is pass a function from parent to child that calls the `setState()` function at the parent's end (Please refer the psuedocode below), but I'm looking for a more robust way of doing this.

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {

  _refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new ChildWidget(
        notifyParent: _refresh(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function notifyParent;
  ChildWidget({@required this.notifyParent});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new FlatButton(
          onPressed: notifyParent(), child: new Text("Update Parent")),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the simplest way I could represent the problem, the `setState()` in the parent (in the actual code) compels the parent widget to update its view.

In the actual code, I have the child widget handling the db queries, a click of the child widget changes the values in the db, and these values are to be updated by parent widget. Hence when I click the child widget, it updates the db then calls the `notifyParent()` which then leads to the parent querying the db again and updating the view.

Is there a better way of doing this without using the `setState()` by using the provider? How can I use say a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to notify of the db changes? Or is there any way I can notify the parent widget whenever something in the db is changed so that the parent can refresh itself?

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you have to notify the parent of an update? That logic seems flawed since the parent doesn't have access to what's inside the child

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The parent needs to be display the items from the db and change as and when they are modified by the child widget, the sole purpose of the parent widget is to display the items in the db. I do feel the logic is flawed, hence looking for a better solution.

Comment: @sujay_br did you find the answer??
If yes then please share...I am also stuck in here.